# Colletion with derived class parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable

I have this classes and method

```
public class Base{ // members;}
public class Derived : Base{// members} 
myMethod(IEnumerable<Base> in1);
```

Try to call `myMethod` like that :

```
myMethod(IEnumerable<Derived > in2);
```

and get compilation error?
how should I solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're expecting is called *covariance*. It means that the actual generic type is more specific than the required one. You can see that covariance does not work for all generic classes: A `List<Derived>` should not be assignable to a `List<Base>`, because then what would happen if you add `Base` intances to the list, which is actually a list of `Derived` instances? So `IEnumerable` is *covariant* and `IList` is *invariant*.

This concept has been applied to the collection classes in [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd233059.aspx). When you are using a version of .NET < 4, those classes are invariant.

Comment: Note that the concept has been introduced way before .NET 4.0, however, in this version it was actually used and C# got the keywords. Also there is _contravariance_, which applies to converting base type to derived type.